# How can I get the IP address of RabbitMQ running from another container (Docker Compose)?

Tags: python, django, docker, rabbitmq, celery

I am following [this](https://medium.com/@tonywangcn/how-to-build-docker-cluster-with-celery-and-rabbitmq-in-10-minutes-13fc74d21730) tutorial. In there, I need to set RabbitMQ IP address to my Celery settings.

I have three containers in my docker-compose.yml: NGINX, Django + Celery, and RabbitMQ. These are all run with `docker-compose up`. However, I need to have the RabbitMQ IP address for celery.py in different container.

Looking through Google, `docker-machine ip <container>` should be the solution. However, `docker-machine` only works for running container, AFAIK. **So, how can I pass container IP address to another container in same docker-compose.yml file?** In this case I want to have my RabbitMQ IP address.

Comment: Are you sure you need the IP address? Will the host name of the container running RabbitMQ not suffice?

Comment: I would expect, because test_celery.py runs in a container from the same docker-compose file, you can simply use `rabbit` (the hostname) in place of that IP address. But I might be wrong, I haven't tried or looked at it in detail.

Comment: I am not so sure as well mate. My Celery configuration is `BROKER_URL = "amqp://admin:asdasdasd@localhost:5672"` and I definetely need to change that `localhost` don't I?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass IPs. Add `link` configs for those services in your `docker-compose.yml`, then reference the containers by service name.

```
services:
  rabbitmq:
    # other config here
  celery:
    # other config ...
    link:
      - rabbitmq
```

Then you can configure Celery to connect with the name rabbitmq. So your `BROKER_URL` setting would be `amqp://user:pass@rabbitmq:5672/queue_name`.

Comment: Link is outdated (just use `network` in docker-compose 3), and also unnecessary when the link name is the same as the service name. But essentially, yes, this is the correct approach.